# Sound of (sea) waves imitation

Tags: sound, doppler, tone-generation

I need to create an algorithm for sound of waves. So I imagine it should be a white noise with doppler effect. However I understand doppler is just change of frequency. But white noise have all the frequencies in it.

What's the basic idea? Is there a simple code already?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rqvqvf6uy8

Comment: OK. Thank you. But how do I apply that wave on the sound of noise? Should I modulate white notice amplitude by that "ocean" wave?

Comment: If you want to go slightly deeper into the topic I recommend to read publications by Joshua Reiss and check out his [FXive](https://fxive.com/#models) project.